# Why do we not have role=logo in HTML?

Tags: html, attributes, semantic-markup

I'm not a fan of using images for site logos, I prefer using text with a designed font style... Since they are just text, browsers and crawlers might not understand what it stands for and I keep wondering how I can initialize my text-based logo to be recognized by HTML.

So I thought of doing something like this:

`<h1 role="logo">Stack Overflow</h1>`

But this isn't correct because there is nothing like role=logo in HTML.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the difference with `role="img"`?

Comment: ``role="img"`` is valid for image logos, do you recommend using it on text-based logo alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want browsers and assistive technologies to interpret something as an image, you can use the [ARIA `img` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img). But don't place this on the `<h1>` element, because the `role="img"` attribute will replace the semantics of the heading with an image. Instead wrap it in a `<span>` and place the `role` attribute on *it*, in order to preserve the heading. Also, don't forget your `aria-label` attribute.

Don't do this:

```
<!-- don't do this -->
<h1 role="img" aria-label="Logo">Logo</h1>

<!-- because it gets interpreted as this -->
<img alt="Logo">
```

Instead, if you must:

```
<!-- if you must, do this -->
<h1><span role="img" aria-label="Logo">Logo</span></h1>

<!-- because it gets interpreted as this, preserving the heading -->
<h1><img alt="Logo"></h1>
```

However, I can't think of any tangible benefits to forcing browsers to see your text logo as an image. You're fine just leaving it as a normal `<h1>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your use case is covered by existing ARIA `img` role. [Quoting the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img):

> Any set of content that should be consumed as a single image (which
> could include images, video, audio, code snippets, emojis, or other
> content) can be identified using role="img".

Comment: It shouldn't be placed on the `<h1>` though, in this context.

Comment: I must say thanks to this, combining this with the instruction issued by @Sean and what i just read from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img) I totally get the idea.